# C++ function memory alignment

Tags: c++, memory

I have read something like that before but unfortunately, forgot some details.

Please, explain function memory alignment:

```
int f(int a = 3, int b = 5) {
    int c = 7;

    int *p = &c;

    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;
    --p;
    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;
    --p;
    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;
    --p;
    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;
    --p;
    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;
    --p;
    std::cout << "Pointer value: " << *p << "\tPointer address: " << p  << std::endl;

    std::cout << "A address: " << &a  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B address: " << &b  << std::endl;

    return c;
}
```

Produces output:

```
Pointer value: 7        Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8dcc
Pointer value: 6299840  Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8dc8
Pointer value: 32748    Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8dc4
Pointer value: -2112316480      Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8dc0
Pointer value: 3        Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8dbc
Pointer value: 5        Pointer address: 0x7ffd62ee8db8
Actual A address: 0x7ffd62ee8dbc
Actual B address: 0x7ffd62ee8db8
```

What is located between function arguments and first object on the stack?

Comment: "What is located between function arguments and first object on the stack?" That's the common hiding place of [nasal demons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Typically, the return address and the value(s) of the caller's stack frame register(s). But it depends on the CPU and calling convention; random memory locations could contain anything or nothing.

Comment: What's your OS and compiler?

Comment: @songziming Ubuntu vivid, Linux 3.16.0-24-generic, g++ 4.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent inquisitiveness.  You're finding out what actually happens when a function is called, which is invaluable information.

The stack is used for more than just storing local variables and function parameters.  The exact layout of the stack contents is dictated by the ABI, an architecture specific description of how functions are called.  So without knowing what architecture this code was written for I can't give you specifics.  But in general these are probably the values of some of the CPU's registers when the function was called.  The function needs to use some of these registers to do its work, so it saves their values on the stack, later it will return those values to their original locations in registers before returning to the calling function (the calling function also pushes the address to return to on the stack).

A great next step would be to pass your compiler the right flags to get it to stop after it generates assembly, but before assembling the resulting object file and executable.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, it's the return address back to the caller

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: You were right but it is not just an address but also some extra data which can be stripped and depends on optimization level